# Add configuration file outside PyInstaller --onefile EXE file into dist directory

Tags: python, pyinstaller

### Situation

I'm using PyInstaller on Windows to make an EXE file of my project.

I would like to use the `--onefile` option to have a clean result and an easy-to-distribute file/program.

My program uses a `config.ini` file for storing configuration options. This file could be customized by users.

### Problem

Using `--onefile` option, PyInstaller puts all declared "data-file"s inside the single `.exe` file.

I've seen [this request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile), but it gives istructions to add a bundle file **inside the onefile** and not outside, at the same level of the `.exe` and in the same `dist` directory.

At some point I've thought to use a shutil.copy command inside .spec file to copy this file... but I think to be in the wrong way.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I have the exact same problem.

Comment: I hope to get some advice to understand if it's possible get this result directly with Pyinstaller. At the moment I've seen a lot of questions about this behavior of - - onefile option without finding the solution.

Comment: Hi @RicardoDuarte I've found an automatic way to add external data files to PyInstaller --onefile command. Take a look to the answer and let me know if it works also for you.

Comment: You can follow the instructions of a simple solution below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63069583/5068961

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[A repository on GitHub](https://github.com/domstoppable/nasa-tlx/blob/db414f532d115b37088ccec12b505d55d01bfb39/build.spec) helped me to find a solution to my question.

I've used the `shutil` module and `.spec` file to add extra data files (in my case, a `config-sample.ini` file) to dist folder using the PyInstaller `--onefile` option.

#### Make a .spec file for PyInstaller

First of all, I've created a makespec file with the options I needed:

```
pyi-makespec --onefile --windowed --name exefilename scriptname.py
```

This command creates an `exefilename.spec` file to use with PyInstaller.

#### Modify exefilename.spec, adding shutil.copyfile

Now I've edited the `exefilename.spec`, adding the following code at the end of the file.

```
import shutil

shutil.copyfile('config-sample.ini', '{0}/config-sample.ini'.format(DISTPATH))
shutil.copyfile('whateveryouwant.ext', '{0}/whateveryouwant.ext'.format(DISTPATH))
```

This code copies the data files needed at the end of the compile process.
You could use all the methods available in the `shutil` package.

#### Run PyInstaller

The final step is to run the compile process

```
pyinstaller --clean exefilename.spec
```

The result is that in the dist folder you should have the compiled .exe file together with the data files copied.

#### Consideration

In the official documentation of PyInstaller I didn't find an option to get this result. I think it could be considered as a workaround... that works.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but I'm still searching for a solution to this question. This answer has a lot of upvotes so I think I'm missing something. This copies the config file to the same directory as the executable, but doesn't appear to have any way of giving the path of the config file to the exe at runtime. That problem is solved in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60937345/how-to-set-up-relative-paths-to-make-a-portable-exe-build-in-pyinstaller-with-p but doesn't solve the problem of having the file in the same dir as the onefile exe

Comment: does it bring excel file from TEMP to actual exe folder? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74172706/pyinstaller-exe-file-pandas-framework-appends-data-to-excel-file-in-temp-folder

Answer (score 7):

Here is how to access files that are on the same level as the output file. The trick is that the sys.executable is where the one-file .exe is located. So simply this does the trick:

```
import sys
import os.path
CWD = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.executable))
```

Use it e.g. with

```
with open(os.path.join(CWD, "config.ini")) as config_file:
    print(config_file.read())
```

### The reason why `os.getcwd()`/relative paths don't work

The executable is just an executable archive that is extracted on execution to a temporary directory, where the *.pyc* files are executed. So when you call `os.getcwd()` instead of the path to the executable, you get the path to the temporary folder.

Answer (score 3):

My solution is similar to [Stefano-Giraldi's excellent solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47886145/63550).  I was getting permission denied when passing directories to the `shutil.copyfile`.

I ended up using `shutil.copytree`:

```
import sys, os, shutil

site_packages = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable), "Lib", "site-packages")
added_files = [
                (os.path.join(site_packages, 'dash_html_components'), 'dash_html_components'),
                (os.path.join(site_packages, 'dash_core_components'), 'dash_core_components'),
                (os.path.join(site_packages, 'plotly'), 'plotly'),
                (os.path.join(site_packages, 'scipy', '.libs', '*.dll'), '.')
                ]
working_dir_files = [
                ('assets', 'assets'),
                ('csv', 'csv')
                ]

print('ADDED FILES: (will show up in sys._MEIPASS)')
print(added_files)
print('Copying files to the dist folder')

print(os.getcwd())
for tup in working_dir_files:
        print(tup)
        to_path = os.path.join(DISTPATH, tup[1])
        if os.path.exists(to_path):
                if os.path.isdir(to_path):
                        shutil.rmtree(to_path)
                else:
                        os.remove(to_path)
        if os.path.isdir(tup[0]):
                shutil.copytree(tup[0], to_path)
        else:
                shutil.copyfile(tup[0], to_path)

#### ... The rest of the spec file
a = Analysis(['myapp.py'],
             pathex=['.', os.path.join(site_packages, 'scipy', '.libs')],
             binaries=[],
             datas=added_files,
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
          cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='myapp',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True)
```

This avoids the _MEI folder and keeps it from copying configuration files that you want in your dist folder and not in a temporary folder.

Answer (score 2):

If any of your Python scripts uses external files (JSON, text or any configuration files) and you wish to include those files in the executable, follow these steps on a **Windows** system.

Considering that there's a Python script `app.py` and it reads a JSON file `config.json`, our goal is to add the `config.json` file in some suitable directory where it can be accessed by the application while it is running (as an `.exe`).

> This answer is applicable even if `app.py` does not read `config.json` directly. `config.json` may be read by any of the modules used by `app.py` and the answer would still help.

```
app.py
config.json
```

##### Step 1: Resolving the path of the JSON file while the application is running

When the application is running, files are copied to a temporary location on your Windows system `C:\Users\<You>\AppData\Local\Temp\MEIxxx`. So, `app.py` needs to read the JSON file from this temporary location. But how would the app know at runtime in which directory it has to search for the files? From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60937345/how-to-set-up-relative-paths-to-make-a-portable-exe-build-in-pyinstaller-with-p) excellent answer, in `app.py`, we'll have a function,

```
def resolve_path(path):
    if getattr(sys, "frozen", False):
        # If the 'frozen' flag is set, we are in bundled-app mode!
        resolved_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, path))
    else:
        # Normal development mode. Use os.getcwd() or __file__ as appropriate in your case...
        resolved_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), path))

    return resolved_path

# While reading the JSON file
with open(resolve_path("config.json"), "r") as jsonfile:
   # Access the contents here
```

Now `app.py` knows *where* to look for the file. Before that, we need to instruct PyInstaller to copy `config.json` into that temporary files directory.

*Note, you need to use the `resolve_path` wherever you are using a relative path in your Python Scripts.*

##### Step 2: Make and edit the `.spec` file to copy `config.json`

As we wish to create an executable of `app.py`, we'll first create a `.spec` file for it, (referring to [@Stefano Giraldi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47886145/13546426))

```
pyi-makespec --onefile --windowed --name appexe app.py
```

Open the resulting `appexe.spec` file, and you'll notice these contents,

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None
a = Analysis(
    ...
    datas=[],
    ...
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    ...
)
```

Create a new list `files` and pass it to the `datas` argument,

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

files = [
    ( 'config.json' , '.' )
]

a = Analysis(
    ...
    datas=files,
    ...
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    ...
)
```

The tuple `('config.json', '.')` denotes the source and destination paths of the file. The destination path is relative to the temporary file directory.

##### Step 3: Build the executable

Finally, we can run the `.spec` file to build the installer,

```
pyinstaller --clean appexe.spec
```

The resulting installer should now run without any `FileNotFoundError`s.

Answer (score 1):

I tried many approaches, and this one worked for me:

1. Do not use the *.py* extension for the configuration file. Use JSON instead. JSON is not good because you can't write comments in it, but if you want to make an EXE file you have to use it unfortunately.
2. Inside your script, load that settings file this way:

   ```
   filename = "settings.json"
   contents = open(filename).read()
   config = eval(contents)
   setting1 = config['setting1']
   ```
3. Run PyInstaller or auto-py-to-exe (I tried both, and all works)
4. Place your *[settings.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908987/how-can-i-open-visual-studio-codes-settings-json-file)* file in the same folder where your *.exe* file is located.
5. Run it and it will take settings from that file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by removing the config file (*config.py* for me) from the project folder before running PyInstaller.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution, but it is not the best:

```py
config_str = """
some configuration code string
"""
with open('path_to_somewhere\\config.ini', 'w', encoding="gbk") as writer:
    writer.write(config_str)
```