# How to bundle the exe file with xml file using pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

```
I have python project as below

sample
    src
        config
            sam.xml
        xmltest.py
```

Here I need to make exe file bundled with sam.xml file. Since xmltest.py depends on sam.xml file for config info i need to bundle the exe with xml as single exe file using pyinstaller.

we can make the exe file with below command. So it can bundled as single exe file.

```
pyinstaller xmltest.py --onefile
```

But sam.xml is not bundled with exe file.

**I need the xml file bundled with exe file not outside the exe or any folder.**

Is there anyway to bundle the xml file with exe using `pyinstaller` or any other way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add config file outside Pyinstaller --onefile exe into dist directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47850064/add-config-file-outside-pyinstaller-onefile-exe-into-dist-directory)

Comment: I need the xml file bundled with exe file not outside the exe or any folder. @ Bernhard

Comment: Because the sam.xml will not be customized by the user

Comment: Sorry, can't you use the add-data parameter in that case?

Comment: Is this one datas=[] in .spec file?

Comment: pyinstaller does have a command line parameter to add data into the --onefile, called --add-data `pyinstaller xmltest.py --onefile --add-data sam.xml` https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/usage.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183876/discussion-between-sathish-and-bernhard).

Comment: pyinstaller xmltest.py --onefile --add-data sam.xml
Does this worked for you?
pyinstaller ....py -w --onefile --add-data ....xml
I had tried this but Mine was giving 
pyinstaller: error: argument --add-data: invalid add_data_or_binary value: '........xml'
this error any help for me @Bernhard