# How to set up relative paths to make a portable .exe build in PyInstaller with Python 3?

Tags: python, build, exe, pyinstaller

I've looked up everywhere and got no definite response to a rather trivial question.

I have a Python project in PyCharm on Windows 7 that contains multiple `.py` files (which are connected via "`from %package_name%.%script_name% import %class_name%`") and a folder inside the project with two simple text files. I've installed PyInstaller 3.6 into project's `venv` and use it as an external tool, that points to a `.spec` file. So far, so good. The `.spec` file is as follows:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['C:\\Users\\%username%\\PycharmProjects\\%project_folder%\\%project_folder%\\main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\%username%\\PycharmProjects\\%project_folder%\\%project_folder%'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('txt_files\\file1.txt', '.'), ('txt_files\\file2.txt', '.')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
a.datas += [
    ("C:\\Users\\%username%\\PycharmProjects\\%project_folder%\\%project_folder%\\txt_files\\file1.txt","txt_files\\file1.txt","DATA"),
    ("C:\\Users\\%username%\\PycharmProjects\\%project_folder%\\%project_folder%\\txt_files\\file2.txt","txt_files\\file2.txt","DATA"),
]
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='%project_name%',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='%project_name%')
```

The problem is that if I hard-code the absolute paths to the bundled `.txt` files in the scripts themselves, the app compiles and has no run-time errors. However, if I use relative paths inside the scripts, the app compiles, but gives a run-time error, that a `.txt` file (i.e. `file1.txt`) is not found INSIDE the `/build` (or `/dist`, I may be wrong here) directory (which is obviously not there).

Of course, hard-coding the absolute paths is a bad practice, especially, when talking not only about portability to another machine, but also making the app cross-platform. I know that the build process may depend on `sys._MEIPASS`, but I don't know exactly how to use it in my context.

In which script (`main`, `.spec` or other?) shall I put the part that gets the absolute path to a bundled file using `sys._MEIPASS`? And how should this code part look like on Python 3.7? I've seen different answers (i.e. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile/)) and already tried them, but none seemed to work in my case.

Comment: Are you bundling into a single file executable (with `--onedir`) or a directory?

Comment: Yes, I want to generate a single bundled executable, but when I passed a `--onedir` option, I got the error `Security-Alert: try to store file outside of dist-directory. Aborting.`. Right now, to get the path to work inside the `venv` in code, I use `file_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), rel_path))`, where `rel_path` is `txt_files\\file1.txt`, and it works inside PyCharm, however, when running the app itself, it generates a `FileNotFoundError` in the `C:\\Users\\%username%\\PycharmProjects\\%project_folder%\\%project_folder%\\dist\\%project_folder%\\txt_files\\file1.txt`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `--onefile` bundles all the datas together into the `.exe` file.

When you execute the file, these files are "unpacked" to a temporary file location. On Windows, this is usually `C:\Users\<You>\AppData\Local\Temp\MEIxxx`.

So, when you are developing your script, the data files (your text files in this example) will be located at

`C:\\Users\\%username%\\PycharmProjects\\%project_folder%\\%project_folder%\txt_files\`

but when the app is compiled, they will be extracted to the temporary directory mentioned above. So you need a way to tell the script whether you are developing, or it has been compiled. This is where you can use [the 'frozen' flag (see the docs here)](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html)

An approach I have used before, is to create a utility function like this

```
def resolve_path(path):
    if getattr(sys, "frozen", False):
        # If the 'frozen' flag is set, we are in bundled-app mode!
        resolved_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, path))
    else:
        # Normal development mode. Use os.getcwd() or __file__ as appropriate in your case...
        resolved_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), path))

    return resolved_path
```

Then whenever you want to use a path in your script, for example accessing your text files you can do

```
with open(resolve_path("txt_files/file1.txt"), "r") as txt:
    ...
```

which should resolve the correct path whichever mode you are in.

### A note on your .spec file

1. You don't have to specify all the text files individually. You can of course, and you may have a good reason for doing so which is fine. But you could do

`datas=[('txt_files', '.')]`

which puts the contents of `txt_files` directory in the root of your bundle. Be careful with this however, because now the paths to your text files will be `<dev directory>\txt_files\file1.txt` but in the bundled app, they will be `<MEIPASS directory>\file1.txt`. You may want to keep the 'relative' part of the path the same by doing

`datas=[('txt_files', 'txt_files')]`

which will mirror the file structure between your development folder and your bundled app.

2. Also consider if you build with the spec file, remove the `COLLECT` part in order to produce a onefile bundled executable.

Comment: Ok, so that's what I have done - I installed the code in the script that reads the files, removed the `COLLECT` from the spec, set `exclude_binaries` to `False` (so that the bundled `.exe` file shall appear in the `dist` directory, like it should), and also added `a.datas` to the `EXE` part of the spec, but now when running the app in Windows console I get the error `Error loading Python DLL 'C:\Users'\%username%\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEIXXXXX\python37.dll LoadLibrary'`, and then some incomprehensible symbols, no matter how I change the `chcp` (probably `One or more arguments are invalid`).

Comment: How do I add Python into the `_MEIPASS` temp directory?

Comment: If you haven't you should add `a.binaries` also to the EXE step.
As a slight aside - it is **much** easier to debug these issues when building in "one directory" mode. Often a good workflow is to get it working like this, and then switch to using `--onedir` once you are sure it's all OK.

Comment: All right, I added `a.binaries` to `EXE` and left the `--onedir` param as it is. Gonna test it now.

Comment: Finally, your solution with bundling mirrored `datas=[('txt_files', 'txt_files')]` worked. Thanks a lot! (don't forget to add closing ticks to the first 'txt_files' in the `datas`, though)

Comment: I would be happy if someone could look at problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74172706/pyinstaller-exe-file-pandas-framework-appends-data-to-excel-file-in-temp-folder

Answer (score 0):

I have the following FS

- GitRepoForMySomeProject

  - MySomeProject

    - main.py
  - MyGitSubmodule
  - ExeSettings.spec
  - ExeVersion.py
  - ExeMySomeProject.bat ("pyinstaller ExeSettings.spec")

In main.py are using some submodule
which placed into subfolder "MyGitSubmodule/ReportGenerator.py"

```python
from MyGitSubmodule import ReportGenerator as _report_
```

Here is my ExeSettings.spec file, with relative path pathex=['../MySomeProject']

```python
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['MySomeProject/main.py'],
             pathex=['../MySomeProject'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='MySomeProject',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False,
          icon='my.ico',
          version='ExeVersion.py')
```

if forget to add this path, we will have

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "MyGitSubmodule"